# How is the IP docker artifactory is running on set?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

i have been dawdleding with docker for some weeks now and am currently trying to set up a CD-pipeline from scratch as a means of learning by doing.

I know i have been messing around with IP-addresses and hostnames at the beginning of my journey with docker but thought i rolled back everything.

One of the things i did at the beginning following some tutorial was changing my /etc/hosts so that i had a mapping

66.66.66.66 my-learning.plattform.com

66.88.88.88 my-other.thingy.com

However, i removed these a week ago or so.
Now when i started the below mentioned docker-compose.yml, trying to reach 
http://localhost:8081/artifactory will timeout as it is being rerouted to
https://66.88.88.88:8081/artifactory/webapp.

When i move the port-mapping for artifactory to 9081:8081 i can reach the webapp, but all settings that are generated include the aforementioned ip.

I checked /etc/resolv.conf, /etc/hosts and am now at a loss what else i could check or what i have missed.

Does anyone have an idea what i have missed?

Thank you in advance

This is my current docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:6.7.1
    container_name: sonarqube
    networks:
      - cd-tools-network
    restart: always
    environment:
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=v07IGCFCF83Z95NX
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonarqube
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins

  db:
    image: postgres:10.1
    container_name: db
    networks: 
      - cd-tools-network
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=v07IGCFCF83Z95NX
      - POSTGRES_DB=sonarqube
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_db:/var/lib/postgresql
      # This needs explicit mapping due to https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/4e48e3228a30763913ece952c611e5e9b95c8759/Dockerfile.template#L52
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  artifactory:                                                                  
    image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest                       
    container_name: artifactory                                                 
    networks:                                                                   
      - cd-tools-network                                                        
    ports:                                                                      
      - 8081:8081                                                                
    environment:                                                                
      - ADMIN_PASSWORD=password                                                  
    volumes:                                                                    
      - /volumes/artifactory:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory                          
#    Add extra Java options by uncommenting the following lines                 
#    environment:                                                               
#     - EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx4g                                               
#     restart: always                                                            
    ulimits:                                                                    
      nproc: 65535                                                              
      nofile:                                                                   
        soft: 32000  
        hard: 40000 

networks:
  cd-tools-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgresql_data:
  sonarqube_bundled-plugins:
  sonarqube_conf:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_db:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  artifactory_db:
  artifactory_db_data:
```